# Python exception handling inside for loop

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and programming in general. While I think this question may be related to my use of exception handling, it might also be due to a general lack of understanding!

```
for i in range(0, len(dates)):
    try:
        data.append(WUF.getwx(location[j], dates[i])[1])
        continue
    except xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError:
        #copy last good row of data and use it for the missing day
        fixdata = data[-1] #[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
        fixdata[10] = 'estimated'
        data.append(fixdata)
```

When I run the code as written, I get 2 "estimated" lines in `data`. One for the previous date, and one for the date that is being estimated. If I change the `fixdata` variable to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]`, then only one line (the intended line for the estimated date) is "estimated".

Any idea what I'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Your 'continue' statement doesn't actually do anything; the for loop will naturally continue after the last line in the try block executes.

Comment: Can you accept one of these answers? They are all very well written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the line:

```
fixdata = data[-1]
```

That doesn't actually copy the data, it only copies the *reference* to the data. `fixdata` ends up pointing to the original element in the list, so when you then do

```
fixdata[10] = 'estimated'
```

it changes the original data.

To actually copy the data, try this:

```
fixdata = data[-1][:]
```

`[:]` copies the whole list, which is what I think you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are appending lists to your `data` list -- creating a 'list of lists'.

That's good -- I'm sure it's what you are intending to do. But in your exception handler, you are actually modifying existing data:

```
fixdata = data[-1]
```

This line assigns a *reference* to the last row in `data` to `fixdata`. At this point, `fixdata` and `data[-1]` are *the same object*. So, when you do this:

```
fixdata[10] = 'estimated'
```

Then the list you are 'fixing' is still inside the `data` list, as well as being referenced by the name `fixdata`. Two names, one object in memory.

When you append it again, with

```
data.append(fixdata)
```

You still aren't copying it; Now, you actually have two references to the very same object inside your `data` list. This is why it looks like you have two 'estimated' lines -- they're one and the same object.

What you really want to do is to make a copy of the last row, rather than just a reference to it. Change your code to this:

```
for i in range(0, len(dates)):
    try:
        data.append(WUF.getwx(location[j], dates[i])[1])
        continue
    except xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError:
        #copy last good row of data and use it for the missing day                 
        fixdata = data[-1][:] #[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
        fixdata[10] = 'estimated'                
        data.append(fixdata)
```

The syntax list[:] is a shorthand for 'each element of this list', and is used as a quick copy operation. Then fixdata will be its own list, and you can change elements of independently of the original.

Answer (score 1):

A couple more comments about your original code sample (outside of the scope of your question)

1. You never actually use the i variable, except to index back into the dates list. One of Python's strengths is its iterators: you can iterate your for loop directly over the items in the list, without having to count them and use an index variable:

   ```
   for date in dates:
   ```
2. Your continue statement doesn't actually do anything. `continue` tells the interpreter to finish this iteration of the for loop immediately, and start the next iteration right away. In this case, there are no statements after the `continue` statement, so the loop would continue naturally, without being told to.
3. There really isn't a need to build up the fixdata variable in two statements, append it in a third, and then discard it  (We're discarding the `fixdata` variable, not its contents) You could do it more succinctly like this:

   ```
   data.append(data[-1][:10] + ['estimated'])
   ```

   In one line, this copies the first 10 elements of the last row into a new list, adds the (very short) list ['estimated'] to the end, and appends it.
4. Your code will run into problems if your very first row throws an exception -- in that case, you won't be able to access `data[-1]` -- trying to do so will throw another exception, which will propagate up. Better to guard against that like this:

   ```
   except xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError:
       if data:
           # do something
   ```

Putting it all together, I would write the code more like this:

```
for date in dates:
    try:
        data.append(WUF.getwx(location[j], date)[1])
    except xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError:
        # as long as we've parsed at least one good row
        if data:
            # copy last good row of data and use it for the missing day
            data.append(data[-1][:10] + ['estimated'])
```

Comment: I don't see how *(in point n.4)* `data[-1]` could have been called if at least one `data.append` wasn't successfull.

Comment: If the very first `WUF.getwx()` call throws an exception, then `data` could still be empty when the exception handler executes

Comment: Oh yes, you are very right. I don't know why but I thought at that `except` like an `else`. Thanks for the clarification +1 :)